# suggestions Don't work in vs code Just in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, autosuggest

when I write Something in vs code by python It dosn't show me the suggestion and when click ctr+space
it show me loading and it still like that .[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcRJP.png)

I think there is problem in setting.json but it looks correct [this is my setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYhhg.png)
notice : this problem happen just when I write python script

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled the IntelliSense feature for Python. Go to the vscode User Settings, search for "python.languageServer" and set it to "Microsoft". If that doesn't work try setting "python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true to enable bracket auto-completion.

Also, do you have the python extension installed for vscode?

If neither of these solutions work, maybe try reinstalling vscode and add the python extension to it.

(Edit: you can try resetting your vscode settings to default. Under **Settings > Open Settings (JSON)** and delete the contents of the file. Then try restarting vscode)

Comment: thank you for trying help me :)  but  neither of these solutions work  . yes I have the python extension installed for vscode  , and i already reinstall it and same problem still happen.

Comment: I see. Maybe you can try resetting your vscode settings to default. Under Settings > Open Settings (JSON) and delete the contents of the file. The try restarting vscode.

Comment: thank you , i deleted vs code and i install last version then the problem sloved

Answer (score 0):

Install the [python interpreter](https://www.python.org/downloads/), then install the [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) for vscode. Add the following configuration in the *settings.json* to get the automatic import feature without any additional settings.

```json
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
```

[image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial*